# pasar de python a Js

Tags: javascript, python

Se necesita pasar este codigo de python a Js

Se reciben los 3 arrays iniciales: tablones A, tablones B y Clavos

```
def solucion(A, B, C): 

    final = len(C)

    inicio = 0

    resultado = -1 

    while final >= inicio: 

        mitad = (inicio + final) / 2

        if checkear(A, B, C, mitad):

            final = mitad - 1

            resultado = mitad

        else:

            inicio = mitad + 1

    return resultado
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y que intentaste para la transformacion? y js y c# son lenguajes muyyyyy diferentes... a cual probaste?

Comment: El codigo en js es practicamente igual... cual es el problema que estas teniendo?

Comment: te falta colocar el codigo del metodo checkear(A, B, C, mitad)

Comment: Pyhton y javascript son lenguajes diferentes, sin embargo ese pequeño código que tienes ahí puede ser transferido a javascript a mano, simplemente debes adaptarlo a la sintaxis de javascript, pero mira, recuerda que nosotros no realizamos lo que un usuario puede hacer, nosotros basados en lo que tu tengas y en algo que no hayas logrado solucionar te ayudamos a solventar el error, mas no "te resolvemos la tarea completa", puesto que esto no te favorece.

Comment: En este caso nos estas pidiendo transcribir un codigo que ya tienes y que ya funciona a un codigo de javascript, algo que se supone con un poco de investigacion lo lograrias muy facil, haz investigado las equivalencias, como declarar variables, los condicionales, etc en javascript?, deberias primero intentar transcribir eso a javascript, luego editar la pregunta y mostrarnos que problema tuviste al intentar pasar a javascript, pues asi tal cual esta la pregunta es un problema que google puede resolver. nosotros no somos google o yahoo.

Answer (score -2):

```
function solucion(A, B, C) {
    var final = C.length;

    var inicio = 0;

    var resultado = -1;

    while (final >= inicio) {
        var mitad = (inicio + final) / 2;

        if (checkear(A, B, C, mitad)) {
            final = mitad - 1;

            resultado = mitad;
        } else {
            inicio = mitad + 1;
        }
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Checa [answer], procura editar y explicar el código y de paso te evitas mas negativos